# vCenter 6, CentOS 7.3, clone from template network issues

Tags: centos, networking, vmware

I was wondering if anyone else has ran into a similar issue.

I created an OVF template off CentOS 7.3. fully updated minimal install. It boots fine, login works, all that stuff. I can set the IPADDR, NETMASK, GATEWAY, etc. in ifcfg-ens160. Now it doesn't happen all the time but randomly the guest cannot send any packets outbound, can't route correctly. Inspecting the routing tables the default entry is correct, and identical to the other guest that is working and cloned off the same template.
No pings, no traceroutes or anything. There are no files under udev/rules.d, vm was attached to the correct Vnic on the correct subnet had outside confirmation of that.

In short, I can configure two vm's exactly identical (same subnet, different 4th octet) and one can talk all day long the other not.
Anyone seen an issue like this before?

Answer (score 1):

*It seems* you have an OVF with a VM image preserving the same MAC address of the original on the (v)NIC cards; possibly an image of a VM with a static defined MAC address.

You cannot have two servers/(v)NIC interfaces in the same network with the same MAC address. As it is a clone with a static-defined MAC address, the MAC addresses of the two servers are identical, and they will enter in a conflict with each other, not being able to work at the same time.

The situation should be easy to debug, run `ifconfig` or `ip link` inside the offending VMs and check the MAC addresses of the interfaces.

To correct it, edit the corresponding VM properties in the VCenter client and change the MAC address(es) of any clone(s), so they will be able to operate concurrently.

Comment: I don't *think* that was it.. I mean I know you can't have multiple identical MAC addresses just like IP addresses.  Fairly certain I checked that but.. maybe not.